# JSON when sent over interservice call using rest template losses some of its value:

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, resttemplate

We send a JSON (Map<String,Object>) from service A to service B.
eg: from source - `{"a":"apple","b":"mango", "c":[{"x":"val1"},{"y":"val2},{"z":"val3}], "d":"cherry"}`
the json i received at destination is
`{"a":"apple","b":"mango", "c":{"z":"val3}, "d":"cherry"}`

C is expected to have list of nested json. Instead received only one value.

Both microservices are deployed in openshift - same cluster

source code

```
responseEntity = this.restTemplateAnsible().exchange(ansiblePBNamesUrl + repoName, HttpMethod.GET, request, Map.class);
LOGGER.info("responseEntity in callAnsiblePlaybookNamesList: {}", responseEntity); //nested json is printed here
Map<String, Object> mapResponse = responseEntity.getBody();
return mapResponse;
```

destination code

```
ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>  responseEntity = restTemplate
                .exchange(cmtServiceAPIName + ansibleServiceUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, mapClass);
        LOGGER.info("responseEntity: " + responseEntity);
```

**Update**
Using JSONNode as return type solved the problem

```
ResponseEntity<JsonNode>     responseEntity = restTemplate
                .exchange(cmtServiceAPIName + ansibleServiceUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, JsonNode.class);
```

But again src json is {"a":"apple","b":"mango", "c":[{"x":"val1", "params":[{"key":"value"}]},{"y":"val2, "params":[{"key":"value"}]},{"z":"val3, "params":[{"key":"value"}]}], "d":"cherry"}

Main json has playbook which is list of json. One of the property inside playbook is params which is again a list. But it is observed that params always contain only one json

In destination, i receive json as {"a":"apple","b":"mango", "c":[{"x":"val1", "params":{"key":"value"}},{"y":"val2, "params":{"key":"value"}},{"z":"val3, "params":{"key":"value"}}], "d":"cherry"}

Is it because params contain only one entry? This data is from third party API. So it may contain more than 1 entry in future. In that case, I dont want my code to break

Comment: Can you check what are you getting when calling responseEntity.getBody()

Comment: I am pretty sure that's due to the fact that the generic type parameter is Object and not the concrete type. I don't think RestTemplate can handle it like that. I think the best option is to probably use JsonNode as a response type and parse it yourself.

Comment: responseEntity.getBody() from source prints {"a":"apple","b":"mango", "c":[{"x":"val1"},{"y":"val2},{"z":"val3}], "d":"cherry"}
responseEntity.getBody() from destination prints {"a":"apple","b":"mango", "c":{"z":"val3}, "d":"cherry"}

Comment: Let me try to use JsonNode now

Comment: cool! using JsonNode solved the issue. thanks @berse2212